# Eating on the Moscow-Dushanbe train?

Tags: trains, russia, restaurants, train-stations, kazakhstan

I'm taking this train to Kazakhstan soon and wonder: does this train have a restaurant car?

If not, where in the Russian cities of Gryazi and Volgograd can I buy food near the station (the train makes long stops there)?

Also, what does food cost, both on the train (if available) and in Gryazi/Volgograd? And if there's a restaurant on the train, what currencies, if any, does it accept besides Tajik somoni and Russian rubles?

I know RZD Trains have Restaurant cars, but this is a Tajik-operated train

Comment: Related: [one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57455/19) and [two](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/59057/19)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For practically any train route in Russia where important long-distance trains pass and at all stations where they stop for more than ten minutes, you can expect an army of *babooshkas* to be waiting, selling their self-made food. In my experience (travelling Moscow–Sludyanka and back), what they sell is pretty good both in taste and in price. So these are always an option.

Also, all long-distance sleeper trains deriving from the Soviet Union will have a hot water supply in every coach — Russians will expect it to be there. Find a supermarket before you leave Moscow, buy some ‘just add water’ stuff and enjoy it on the way. (Also take tea bags or instant coffee, whichever your favourite hot drink may be.)

On the topic of accepted currencies should there be a restaurant car: I can only speak from experience with RZD, but their restaurant on the Moscow–Vladivostok train would not accept anything other than rubles in cash. I would not bet on the train accepting anything else while in Russia (Yes, that includes credit cards).

Comment: Thing is, this is not an RZD train, but a Tajik-operated one. I know RZD Trains have Restaurant cars, but this one I cannot seem to find any info on

Comment: Also do you remember what the Food cost? What I'm trying to figure out is how many rubles I should bring (one meal per day is enough, and the trip lasts from day 1 at 12:16 to day 3 at 16:30)

Comment: @Crazydre Yeah, I had a stronger *no*-sentence there before, then I browsed the other questions and realised the Tajik thing.

Comment: The price’ll depend on what you buy, who’s selling it, how much she wants to make advantage of faraway tourists or whatnot. But expect it to be cheap.

Comment: So roughly how many rubles for a meal would be a safe assumption? 100 rubles? 200? 300? Etc. Just so I have an idea when calculating the amount of rubles I should buy for this trip

Comment: Really depends on how much you need. If I remember correctly, two pirogi were something like 60 rubles. But memory’s fuzzy there .__.''