# Vegetarian dishes on Russian trains (European part)

Tags: trains, food-and-drink, russia, dietary-restrictions

On Russian long-distance trains that include restaurant cars, should I in 2019 expect that I can buy full vegetarian dishes there?  On those [pictures of a 2015 menu on the Trans Siberian Express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA8Nb.jpg) linked by [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/57532/2509), it seems that virtually every dish contains meat or fish.  Should I expect difficulties as an ovo-lacto-vegetarian (but not vegan)?

I will be travelling in classes 2К and 2Т on trains [024Й](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=91e2cd), [042В](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=66278f40), [041М](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=4be2a81d), and [009Щ](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=edc504), where the trains do appear to have some [10 minute+ stops](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/59058/2509) to stock up on food (and water) off-train if food on the train is too limited, assuming such is available on the platform.

Comment: Vodka is vegetarian :)

Comment: I have fairly much assumed that vegetarian dishes would be unavailable which led me to ask this question: https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/vegan-survival-food.

Comment: @badjohn Thanks a lot for the link.  I'm going to use this as an opportunity to finally try one of those complete food products!

Comment: They don't appeal to me much.  I wouldn't use them if more normal food was available.  However, they seem to fulfil this requirement.

Comment: Of course down-voting is allowed, but I would appreciate if some of the four down-voters could comment on how they think the question can be improved, made clearer, made more useful, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On all Russian trains I have taken, vegetarian food was no problem.  The vegetarian options were much better than on British, French, or Spanish trains.  I did not need to use my backup option.

For the domestic trains Moscow - Vorkuta and Vorkuta - Moscow, the *проводник* asked me what kind of food I wanted.  When I told her I was vegetarian, she said, no problem.  I was served cous cous with vegetables, complete with a *Vegetarian* sticker which is evidence that they are prepared for this situation:

[image: Image with a closed meal box and a green sticker *вез мяса / Vegetarian*]

The restaurant car also had plenty of vegetarian options, and I ate my breakfast, lunch, and dinner there.  The vegetarian options were marked bilingually and what I wanted was always available.

The international train Paris-Moscow also had plenty of vegetarian options in its menu, which were mostly available.  The restaurant car was Polish.

The international train Moscow-Warsaw did not have a restaurant car, so it had neither vegetarian nor non-vegetarian dishes.

Incidentally, the international train Warsaw-Berlin, which is Polish, has the best vegetarian food I've ever had on a train, a tofu-walnut salad that would not be misplaced in a fancy vegetarian restaurant in Berlin.

Comment: I have taken and added this image on purpose. I have reverted an edit which deleted it; the sticker shows evidence that the Russian railways are clearly prepared for this situation, which I think is an important piece of information.

Comment: Ok, your choice. Nice post though, +1

Comment: Makes me wonder what the word 'ham' in Russian actually means ;-)

Comment: I don't doubt for a moment that the trains you caught were as you describe, though I do wonder whether this was typical.  In my experience of Russian trains over the last few years, it's not uncommon to find they only have a single dish available, and it's not vegetarian.  If that's starting to change, then I'm pleased.  But – and this is the reason I am posting this comment – if another traveller comes along and reads this answer, I would be very wary of accepting it as the normal situation.  The answer by @jpatokal, above, is much closer to my experience.

Comment: @gerrit Out of curiosity, which train & class of service was this?  I'm glad this worked out well for you, but on the Trans-Siberian last year there were definitely no boxed meals, much less vegetarian couscous (!), and even the borscht was mostly *nyet*.

Comment: @Berend нам (nam) is a conjugation of "we", so нам с вами по пути is roughly "we are with you along the way".

Comment: @jpatokal 2К and 2Т on trains 042В and 041М (see question), with "komfort".

Answer (score 29):

**No**, you definitely cannot count on having vegetarian meals on long-distance trains in Russia.  In fact even the menu is misleading, as quite commonly only a very limited selection of dishes are *actually* available on any given train.

Beware that fresh/hot food selections at stations are also quite limited, and vegetarian options even more so.  (They've cracked down on unlicensed sellers, they need to rent stalls now and this has cut down on the selection a lot.)  Vegetarianism in general is poorly understood in Russia, and even notionally vegetarian Russian staples like *piroshki* cabbage pastries may contain lard.

You're not going to starve, because you can always buy vegetarian packaged snacks (potato chip, peanuts, etc), but I would strongly encourage you to bring along enough staples to last you until your next stop.  Hot water for noodles, porridge etc is always available.

You may find my little review of food options on the Trans-Siberian last year useful: https://driftingclouds.net/2018/07/04/from-siberia-to-tibet-life-on-a-train/

Comment: As soon as we entered Belarus, women came onto the train selling potato cakes (vegetarian), and in Russia too I saw at train stations not only stalls but also women (rarely men) walking around with plastic bags selling stuff.  Incidentally, I had [no problem at all](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147476/2509) buying vegetarian food on the trains (it was much harder in the town of Inta).  I brought along staples as a back-up, but I did not need to use them.

Comment: I really enjoyed your blog post. Thanks for sharing :-)

Answer (score 13):

@jpatokal is right, "you definitely cannot count on having vegetarian meals on long-distance trains in Russia" (as well as on a menu).

However, there might be something in a restaurant car as, e.g., a salad suitable for a vegetarian. In fact, I traveled with a vegetarian girl this July on [056Ы](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=35d436), and she was quite happy with salads from a restaurant car and vegetarian snacks we bought on train stations.

There are classes where you can [preorder food](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5334) (full board, half board (breakfast, dinner), only breakfast or lunch or dinner, with a choice from the menu -- unfortunately, I cannot find this info in English). Breakfast is usually a porridge (kasha); however, I don't know whether you are OK with milk or not. [Here](https://sandreyo.livejournal.com/74480.html) a passenger provides a review on food options on the Trans-Siberian in 2018 when you preorder food online (the review is in Russian but full of pictures).

Comment: I can have milk, eggs, honey, etc.  I'm vegetarian and one rule of thumb is that I don't eat what I wouldn't feel comfortable "harvesting" ;-)

Comment: Does preordering food make any difference for a vegetarian?  Can one order food with special dietary restrictions?

Comment: The picture in your preorder food link actually does show a picture of vegan food.

Comment: @gerrit concerning special dietary restrictions, I don't think so. Actually, the guy providing the review (the third link in my answer) shows that you can choose from "standard", "child", and "vegetarian" and what's inside the chosen option depends on the type of railroad car (сouchette car/platzkart, corridor coach/coupé, sleeping car (I class)/sv etc.) you travel in.

Comment: Preordering food does make a difference because otherwise you definitely cannot count on having vegetarian meals in a restaurant car even though they are on a menu.

Comment: Interesting!  I couldn't readily find out how to preorder food, so [I've asked a new question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144036/2509).

Comment: I found out how to preorder food that I already paid for and tried: the choices were "rice with chicken" and "pasta with meat".  Maybe I should have bought the ticket that did not include meals...

Comment: Finally, it was [no problem at all](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147476/2509) to get vegetarian food on the train.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend to bring along food. Train restaurant car's dishes are not popular. It's not the same as meal in planes.

Comment: Is this general advice or specific to Russian trains?

Comment: I suppose it's specific to Russian trains.  On trains in the US and Canada (Amtrak and Via Rail), the meals in the restaurant cars on the long distance trains are excellent.  In Sweden, UK, Germany, France, Spain it's mediocre to intermediate, certainly better than on planes where it ranges from poor (most airlines I've flown) to outright disgusting (British Airways).

Comment: Yes, defenitely in Russian trains and in Kazakhstan trains.

Comment: I agree that the restaurant car is not popular, but I found the food there good, cheap, and with enough vegetarian options.  I suspect that by Russian standards they're expensive (430 roubles for breakfast, at the hostel the same was maybe 200 roubles), but for a westerner it's still cheap.